# Why does the filter function in the dplyr package show error "Each variable must be named"?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use the `filter()` in the dplyr package. I am getting some error. I would appreciate some kind of help.

```
f<-filter(data_frame, data_frame$Brand=="Apple")
```

I am getting this:

> Error: Each variable must be named. Problem variables: 1

Comment: Can you add an example of your dataset? I remember having the same issue some days ago. If some of your columns are not named, dplyr won't work. I named all columns (`colnames(data_frame) <- c("colname1", "colname2")`) and had no more problems.

Comment: Another hint: You don't need to use `data_frame$`in front of the column name Brand. You told the filter to use `data_frame` before.

Answer (score -1):

data_frame=data.frame(Brand=c("Apple", "Acer"))

data_frame %>% filter(Brand=="Apple")